# Can I add edit option and give it functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

So here's what I want to do, I have taken an edit button in my code and I want to add edit functionality to it so How can I do it using js. Also there is cancel button in my code and when I click it the selected option in my row should get deleted I did this using remove() function of js but the problem is if the user adds 2 or 3 select input and then if he starts deleting the selected option from start it is working just fine but if the user start cancelling the last option it cancels the first rather than canceling the 1 option so what should I do here is the block of code I am working:

```
<form action="" id="order-form">
            <h1 class="text-center">Place An Order</h1>
            <div class="row mx-2">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>order you placed:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>your order type</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>Quantity</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mx-2" id="placedOrder">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" id="forOrder"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" id="forOrderType"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3" id="forQuantity"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3" id="forBtn"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mx-2" id="order-container">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" id="div1">
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <select class="form-select myOrder" id="floatingSelectGrid"
                            aria-label="Floating label select example">
                            <option disabled selected>Open this select menu</option>
                            <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
                            <option value="Mutton">Mutton</option>
                            <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
                            <option value="Fish">Fish</option>
                            <option value="Marinades">Marinades</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Select Order</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <select class="form-select orderType" id="floatingSelectGrid"
                            aria-label="Floating label select example">
                            <option disabled selected>Open this select menu</option>
                            <option value="Broiler">Broiler</option>
                            <option value="Cockrele">Cockrele</option>
                            <option value="Laygon">Laygon</option>
                            <option value="Country">Country</option>
                            <option value="Layer">Layer</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Order Type</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control orderQty" id="floatingNumberGrid" min="1" max="999"
                            placeholder="name@example.com" value="Quantity">
                        <label for="floatingNumberGrid">Add Quantity(in kg.)</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-sm-4 col-md-2 my-3 mx-auto">
                    <button type="button" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
                        onclick="addMyOrder()">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

<script>
        function addMyOrder() {

            let myOrder = document.getElementsByClassName("myOrder")[0].value;
            let orderType = document.getElementsByClassName("orderType")[0].value;
            let orderQty = document.getElementsByClassName("orderQty")[0].value;

            const para1 = document.createElement("p");
            const node1 = document.createTextNode(`${myOrder}`);
            para1.id = "myOrder";
            para1.appendChild(node1);

            const para2 = document.createElement("p");
            const node2 = document.createTextNode(`${orderType}`);
            para2.id = "myOrderType"
            para2.appendChild(node2);

            const para3 = document.createElement("p");
            const node3 = document.createTextNode(`${orderQty}`);
            para3.id = "myOrderQty"
            para3.appendChild(node3);

            const element1 = document.getElementById("forOrder");
            element1.appendChild(para1);

            const element2 = document.getElementById("forOrderType");
            element2.appendChild(para2);

            const element3 = document.getElementById("forQuantity");
            element3.appendChild(para3);

            const element4 = document.getElementById("forBtn");

            let para5 = document.createElement("input");
            para5.type = "button";
            para5.name = "edit";
            para5.id = "forEdit";
            para5.value = "Edit";
            para5.className = "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm me-2 mb-2";
            para5.addEventListener('click', editOrder);
            element4.appendChild(para5);

            let para4 = document.createElement("input");
            para4.type = "button";
            para4.name = "delete";
            para4.id = "forDelete";
            para4.value = "Cancel";
            para4.className = "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm me-3 mb-2";
            para4.addEventListener('click', cancelOrder);
            element4.appendChild(para4);
        }

        function cancelOrder() {
            let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this order?");
            if (confirmAction) {
                let toCancel1 = document.getElementById("myOrder");
                let toCancel2 = document.getElementById("myOrderType");
                let toCancel3 = document.getElementById("myOrderQty");
                let toCancel4 = document.getElementById("forEdit");
                let toCancel5 = document.getElementById("forDelete")

                toCancel1.remove();
                toCancel2.remove();
                toCancel3.remove();
                toCancel4.remove();
                toCancel5.remove();
            }
            else {
                alert("Order is not cancelled.");
            }
        }

function editOrder() {
            let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this order?");

            if (confirmAction) {

            } else {
                alert("Order is not edited")
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.